# Describe statistical model of n binomial random variables

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

Let $$X = (X_{1},..., X_{n})$$ consist of iid random variables s.t.
$$X_{i}\sim Bin({m,\theta }),$$ for known$$m \in \mathbb{N},$$
and unknown$$ \theta \in (0,1)$$

Describe statistical model including $$ S, f_{\theta},\Theta $$

So far I have:

$$S = [0,1,...,m]^{n}$$
$$\Theta=(0,1)$$
$$f_{\theta_{i}}= \begin{pmatrix}
m  \\x_{i}
\end{pmatrix} \theta^{x_{i}}(1-\theta)^{m-x_{i}}$$
$$f_{\theta}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}
m  \\x_{i}
\end{pmatrix} \theta^{x_{i}}(1-\theta)^{m-x_{i}}$$

not sure how to simplify last expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far so good. Firstly we can use that $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} f(i)\cdot g(i)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} f(i)\cdot \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} g(i)$, where $f(i), g(i)$ are arbitrary terms which depends on index $i$.

$$f_{\theta}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}
m  \\x_{i}
\end{pmatrix} \theta^{x_{i}}(1-\theta)^{m-x_{i}}$$

$$=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}
m  \\x_{i}
\end{pmatrix} \cdot  \prod_{i=1}^{n} \theta^{x_{i}}\cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-\theta)^{m-x_{i}}$$

Then $\prod_{i=1}^{n} \theta^{x_{i}}=\theta^{x_{1}}\cdot \theta^{x_{2}}\cdot \ldots \cdot \theta^{x_{n}}=\theta^{\, \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i} $

$$=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}
m  \\x_{i}
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \theta^{\, \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i}\cdot (1-\theta)^{\, \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (m-x_i)}$$

$$=\theta^{\, \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i}\cdot (1-\theta)^{\, \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (m-x_i)}\cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}
m  \\x_{i}
\end{pmatrix}  $$